# group array of object by dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I have a data structure that look like this

```
const arr = [{
    name: "Alice",
    created_at : "2017-04-18"
},
{
    name: "James",
    created_at : "2017-06-30"
},
{
    name: "Melisa",
    created_at : "2017-04-03"
},
{
    name: "Amy",
    created_at : "2017-05-03"
}];
```

I want to restructure it so that I can display them. I want to display them by month, like so

April 
- Alice
- Melisa

May
- Amy

June
- James

I have no clue where to begin.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses moment and lodash.

First we create a helper function that uses [**moment**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to create a date and then then extract the shortened month name.

```
// helper function to get the month name from an item
const monthName = item => moment(item.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMM');
```

Now use lodash to [**group by**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) date and then [**map**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) across each group to get the names for each group. The following snippet uses implicit [**chaining**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chain):

```
// group items by month name and then get the name for each month
const result = _(arr)
    .groupBy(monthName)
    .mapValues(items => _.map(items, 'name'))
    .value()
```

As above but with explicit chaining:

```
// group items by month name and then get the name for each month
const result = _.chain(arr)
    .groupBy(monthName)
    .mapValues(items => _.map(items, 'name'))
    .value()
```

**UPDATE**

To get all the items for each month then it simplifies to just this:

```
const result = _.groupBy(arr, monthName);
```

`result` will now look like this:

```
{
    Apr: [
        { name: "Alice", created_at : "2017-04-18" },
        { name: "Melisa", created_at : "2017-04-03" }
    ],
    Jun: .....
}
```

Comment: wow the first line blow my time, I didn't know function can be 1 line just like that.

Comment: where does _(arr) come from?

Comment: what if I have multiple property besides names? how the mapValues callback look like?

Comment: Learned something today, thank you for your clear explanation Gruff!

Comment: There's a problem with this `const result = _.groupBy(arr, monthName);` if the list is long. I will have multiple same months. Can groupBy handle that?

Comment: `groupBy` should handle the list regardless of length. Does the format of the list change in some way?

Comment: Can groupBy distinct '2014-04-01' and '2017-04-01'? I afraid it same both but 2 different yrs got merged into object, that's my concern.

Comment: actually I'm also facing another problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715974/react-map-returned-error-of-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child/43716044#43716044

Comment: To group by year and month change the format string to `'YYYY-MMM'`. The keys in the result object will then look like: '2017-Apr' etc. I'm afraid I don't know react so it may be worth posting a second question

Comment: `const result = _.groupBy(arr, monthName);`  What I need to add to get in result incomes sum(second array property) by month? Same case but instead of name I have num string value.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`moment#format`](http://momentjs.com/) to get the name of the month and use this with [`lodash#groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to group the items by months. Lastly, use [`lodash#mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues) and [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to transform each item by name.

```
var result = _(arr)
  .groupBy(v => moment(v.created_at).format('MMMM'))
  .mapValues(v => _.map(v, 'name'))
  .value();
```

```js
const arr = [{
    name: "Alice",
    created_at : "2017-04-18"
},
{
    name: "James",
    created_at : "2017-06-30"
},
{
    name: "Melisa",
    created_at : "2017-04-03"
},
{
    name: "Amy",
    created_at : "2017-05-03"
}];

var result = _(arr)
  .groupBy(v => moment(v.created_at).format('MMMM'))
  .mapValues(v => _.map(v, 'name'))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if I have multiple property besides names? how the mapValues callback look like?

Comment: @ryeballar what if have multiple stuff apart from names and just want to get back the full data but just grouped by the month.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```js
var res = [
    {month:"January",elems:[]},
    {month:"February",elems:[]},
    {month:"March",elems:[]},
    {month:"April",elems:[]},
    {month:"May",elems:[]},
    {month:"June",elems:[]},
    {month:"July",elems:[]},
    {month:"August",elems:[]},
    {month:"September",elems:[]},
    {month:"October",elems:[]},
    {month:"November",elems:[]},
    {month:"December",elems:[]}
];

const arr = [{
        name: "Alice",
        created_at: "2017-04-18"
    },
    {
        name: "James",
        created_at: "2017-06-30"
    },
    {
        name: "Melisa",
        created_at: "2017-04-03"
    },
    {
        name: "Amy",
        created_at: "2017-05-03"
    }];
arr.forEach(function(e){
    var month =parseInt(e.created_at.substring(5,7)) - 1;
    res[month].elems.push(e);
});
res.forEach(function (e) {
    if (e.elems.length > 0) {
        console.warn(e.month);
        e.elems.forEach(function (n) {
            console.info(n.name);
        });
        console.log('------------------------');
    }
});
console.log(res);
```

I hope this works :)

Comment: sort is es2015 method?

Comment: sort for? I just don't get it. I think you misunderstood what I want.

Comment: I changed my code,And you was write I misunderstood your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can group them using `key-value` pairs like this using plain javascript. You will also get it in `sorted` order automatically

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Alice", created_at : "2017-04-18" }, { name: "James", created_at : "2017-06-30" }, { name: "Melisa", created_at : "2017-04-03" }, { name: "Amy", created_at : "2017-05-03" }];

var m =['','January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

var result={}

// restructuring loop
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  var month = parseInt(arr[i].created_at.substring(5,7))
  if(!result[month]){
    result[month] = [arr[i].name]
  }
  else{
    result[month].push(arr[i].name)
  }
}

//display loop
for (var k in result){
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         console.log(m[k]+'-->'+result[k])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group them based on the month, then use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with a reference object to hold the index.

```js
const arr = [{
  name: "Alice",
  created_at: "2017-04-18"
}, {
  name: "James",
  created_at: "2017-06-30"
}, {
  name: "Melisa",
  created_at: "2017-04-03"
}, {
  name: "Amy",
  created_at: "2017-05-03"
}];

// refernce object for holding the index
var ref = {};

var res = arr.reduce(function(arr1, o) {
  //  get month value
  var m = new Date(o.created_at).getMonth();
  // check already defined in the reference array
  if (!(m in ref)) {
  // define if not defined
    ref[m] = arr1.length;
    // push an empty array
    arr1.push([]);
  }
  // push the object into the array
  arr1[ref[m]].push(o);
  // return array refernece
  return arr1;
  // set initial value as an empty array for result
}, []);


console.log(res);


// to print as in your question
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

//  iterate over the generated array
res.forEach(function(v) {
  // get month name from array and generate name by concatenating the name
  console.log(monthNames[new Date(v[0].created_at).getMonth()] + ' ' + v.map(function(o) {
    return o.name;
  }).join());
})
```

Comment: fuh so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

```
const roots = {}

arr.forEach((item) => {
      const formattedDate = formatDateString(item.created_at, 'MMMM yyyy')
      const currentList = roots[formattedDate] ?? []
      Object.assign(roots, { [formattedDate]: [...currentList, item] })
    })
```

Create a method that can format your date to a specific format, this will be your key inside the object.