# react map returned error of Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I failed to render jxs using map of lodash. I have this in my render method

```
return (
    <div>
    {map(groupedByMonths, (obj, index) => 
        <div className="panel">
        <div className="panel-heading">
        {obj}
        </div>
        <div>{obj.price}</div>
        </div>)}
    </div>
    )
```

But I got error of `Objects are not valid as a React child` The `groupedByMonths` structure look like this

```
{
    "April": [
        {
            "price": 0,
        },
        {
            "price": 12
        },
        {
            "price": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is working for me https://codepen.io/ashafir20/pen/ybbjzZ?editors=1010

Comment: @radix how can I show 'April'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how to do this with `lodash map`, i can suggest this:

```
{Object.keys(groupedByMonths).map((obj, index) => 
     <div className="panel">
         <div className="panel-heading">
             {obj}
         </div>
         {groupedByMonths[obj].map((el, i) => <div key={i}> {el.price} </div>)}
     </div>)
}
```

When we use `Object.keys(groupedByMonths)` it will return an `array` that will contain all the keys, and we can use `map` on that. To print the key use `{obj}` and to print the values use `{groupedByMonths[obj]}`.

Comment: Nope, April is dynamic sir. I have to show the month and the item within.

Comment: How can I show the month if I have April, May and June?

Comment: @AlanJenshen check the updated answer, don't know how to use lodash map, you can use this it will work :)

Comment: this is so genius, ah I need 2 loops! Object.keys does the job, thanks Mayank!